# Creating custom sized PDFs from MS Excel using VBA Macros

Tags: excel, vba, page-size

I created an MS Excel macro that generates payment receipts as PDF files.
I created a receipt template in one of the tabs. When the code is run the macro loads values from another tab into the template and generates PDF from the template tab.
However the page sizes available in Excel are very limited. My receipt size is probably a bit smaller than A5. Is there any way I can customize the page size on VBA so that my receipts looks more neat?

Comment: This might help: https://excel.tips.net/T009389_Defining_a_Custom_Paper_Size.html

Comment: Thank you Viktor. I went through the link, but not exactly what I am looking for. I do not have a printer with me and I am trying to make a portable tool, so the paper size customization might not work with other users too